# SQL Dependency & SignalR - Two web apps with the same code, one is working while the other is not

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, signalr, signalr-hub

#### Brief Introduction:

> There's a **TL;DR** at the end (:

I have two versions of a web app that uses SQL Dependency and SignalR to automatically refresh views when a change in DB is detected.

The previous version of the application works correctly, while the new version does not. **The strange thing is that, at first sight, both versions have the same code, there was no change in the part of SignalR between both web apps.**

- What could this be?
- Is there anything else that I should keep in mind and that I have forgotten?
- How can it be that the code that is responsible for triggering the refresh event when a change in the database occurs does not trigger the event?

---

#### NotifierEntity.cs:

When you start the application, both versions correctly execute the following code in the backend:

```
void RegisterForNotifications()
{
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(notificationEntity.SqlConnectionString))
    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(notificationEntity.SqlQuery, sqlConnection))
    {
        foreach (var sqlParameter in notificationEntity.SqlParameters)
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

        sqlCommand.Notification = null;
        var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(sqlCommand);
        sqlDependency.OnChange += OnSqlDependencyChange;
        if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The `OnChange`event in the new version is never triggered.

---

#### The view I want to refresh:

The view I want to refresh automatically contains the following script, whose function is to subscribe to the event of changing a table in the DB.
**Like the code above, this code is the same between both versions of the web app.**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/anotherScript.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var signalRHubInitialized2 = false;

    $(function () {
        InitializeSignalRHubStore2();
    });
    function InitializeSignalRHubStore2() {
        if (signalRHubInitialized2)
            return;
        try {
            var clientHub2 = $.connection.hubNotificacion;
            clientHub2.client.updateTableVehicles = function (message) {
                if (message === "Refresh")
                    ReloadIndexPartial2();
            };
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                clientHub2.server.initializeTableDependencyVehicles();
                signalRHubInitialized2 = true;
            });
        } catch (err) {
            signalRHubInitialized2 = false;
        }
    };
    function ReloadIndexPartial2() {
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

---

#### The Hub:

When you load the view and run that script, the following hub code is accessed in the backend. The first part of the code seems to work just fine in both versions of the web application:

```
public void InitializeTableDependencyVehicles()
{
    if (!flag)
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            string data = db.GetNotifierEntity<Vehicle>(db.Vehicles).ToJson();
            NotifierEntity NotifierEntity1 = NotifierEntity.FromJson(data);
            Action<String> dispatcher = (t) => { DispatchToClientTablesVehicles(); };
            PushSqlDependency.Instance(NotifierEntity1, dispatcher);
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But the second code automatically runs **only on one of the versions** of the web application. The other version does not seem to trigger the refresh event when a record is updated in the database.  Please remember that, to the naked eye, both webs have the same code in the SignalR and SQL Dependency part.

```
public void DispatchToClientTablesVehicles()
{
    Clients.All.updateTableVehicles("Refresh");
}
```

---

### TL;DR

Two versions of the same web app have the same code, however one of the versions of the web app detects the changes in the DB and triggers one event while the other version does not.

> - Both Web Applications run the same code (the SignalR and SQL Dependency stuff)
> - One Web Application **does** refresh automatically the view, but the other **does not**.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You'll need to debug: look for client side errors, network errors, try to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mason I've already debugged the code and the `OnChange` event in the new version is never triggered. I can't debug the _database pooling_ since it's not part of my code.

Comment: Did you make sure the `OnChange` event handler gets wired up? Did you make sure it's looking at the correct database? Did you make sure the correct tables/views get changed? These are the sorts of debugging steps I'm talking about. When something isn't working, you check all parts of the chain until you figure out where exactly it stops working.

Comment: Are your working with the same database in both applications or they are different ?

Comment: @mason Yes, indeed the `OnChange` event handler is correctly linked, it is pointing to the correct database and the table that is modified in the database is correct.

Comment: Needs a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or else we're just guessing

Comment: How do you know though? Are you saying that just because you looked at the code? Or did you step through it line by line to see that it's wired up? And why are you using `SqlDependency` in a web application? That needs a background thread, and running your own background thread in ASP.NET is a bad idea. That belongs in a separate (non-ASP.NET) service.

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj They are different versions of the same database.

Comment: Did you check if your second version has `ENABLE_BROKER` set ?

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj Yes, both databases have the broker enabled.

Comment: @SantiagoChiappa are those two versions of your application hosted in IIS as two separate applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by deleting the database and creating it again.
I have generated the scripts to fill again the data and it worked again.

Important: restoring the database from a *.bak* backup file didn't worked. I had to create a new database from scratch.

P.S. (so that you avoid later headaches): I've noticed that SignalR stops working quickly as some concurrent connections are generated. It's not a good idea if you're planning to log in with 10 users at the same time.